# Predicting values in time series for future periods with windowed dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, prediction

I have the data till 3650 time steps, but I want to make future predictions i.e. data after 3650 time steps. I am new to machine learning, and apparently can't figure it out. How can I do it?
For reference,
[Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%204%20-%20S%2BP/S%2BP%20Week%204%20Exercise%20Answer.ipynb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach of how to adapt tabular (or cross-sectional) regression algorithms to forecasting problems is described [here](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/41231210/Machine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser20160114-28513-1pqgoe9.pdf20160115-19908-phg1xc.pdf?1452888125=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DMachine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser.pdf&Expires=1591446976&Signature=KbtlBoQ9O%7ETROgo8AuK94U2O-BbERykqDk4HCGV0HNPnXECBPlSv500cQ49dZ-qsYH1u2iq6JS6a-oh4yO2T45kfGJqckKp7P-M%7EOcbhlpqRA3CtD832SGTcavThNR58mfmF25eN7x5qN137eyBJGrfNmtC0f-ZVRIs%7EZRafSrYMKeykvXc7m12DKKuprq%7EdslLaDHV-OOvJb5f42aAH0PUb-MrN72Cka3Y1DO7hPUVCnD1XmpLNBc7I4-yrAO8GKKvd9-4i9V1NpauHfShnDD65zO2n8avUeMx86%7EizSvscSNRwW2qZXkZmXSUTvyOWrcJpSyvUmK2I3kTbQxBVcg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA). In short: you train your model on windows of lagged observations. To generate forecasts, you have different options, with the recursive strategy most commonly used, here you use the last available window to forecast the first value, then update the last window with the first forecasted value to forecast the next value and so on.

If you're interested, we're developing a toolbox that extends scikit-learn for exactly these use cases. So with [sktime](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime), you could simply write:

```
import numpy as np
from sktime.datasets import load_airline
from sktime.forecasting.compose import RecursiveTabularRegressionForecaster
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.performance_metrics.forecasting import mean_absolute_percentage_error
y = load_airline()  # load 1-dimensional time series
y_train, y_test = temporal_train_test_split(y)  
fh = np.arange(1, len(y_test) + 1)  # forecasting horizon
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=3)  
forecaster = RecursiveTabularRegressionForecaster(regressor, window_length=10)
forecaster.fit(y_train)
y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh)
print(mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, y_pred, symmetric=True))
>>> 0.1440354514063762
```